# How to configure the filename length that can be handled by Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, tomcat, liferay, ubuntu-9.04

Im using Liferay portal server on tomcat and Linux Ubuntu.

Liferay is generating a file that is very long. I've seen those files in windows and its working. But when i tried running it in ubuntu, it doesn't create the file and my server is giving me error. I've also tried to make a file with a very long filename and it really doesn't allow me.

Is there a way for Linux Ubuntu to allow me to do this?

Comment: Maybe an example of the error message would help.

Comment: if i make a file that has this filename : everything.jsp_Q_browserId=firefox&themeId=controlpanel&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&t=1249034302000

it wouldn't allow and brings up an error that says your filename is too long...

Answer (score 5):

Fix this...

The source of my problem is the encrypted home of my ubuntu OS. It seems that the filename of the file created is also encrypted making my long filename even longer.

When i made a new installation of my Ubuntu, i didn't encrypt my home anymore and it works fine now.. thanks a lot all...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu 9.10 machine and I think it really was caused by the home-directory encryption. Those "too long" filenames work fine outside my home.

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge slew of reasons it may not be working, probably the least of which is a long file name (unless we're talking about a filename over 255 characters, which I believe is the hard-limit).

Also, file length isn't going to be a big problem unless you've got some truly enormous files (sometimes linux filesystems cap at 2GB, but I don't know what the behaviour is if you went over. You'd probably still see a 2GB file that just doesn't contain everything).

My knee-jerk reaction would be to say you're having a permissions problem where the user the server is running as (say, 'www' or 'www-data', or whatever) doesn't have permission to write in the folder its trying too.

Comment: thank you for that answer. and yes, my filename is very long long. 

everything.jsp_Q_browserId=firefox&themeId=controlpanel&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&t=1249034302000 

thats the filename im talking about. How can i make my Linux Ubuntu 9.04 make this filename?

Comment: I don't think its possible.There's a hard limit on the filename size. Maybe save them as <MD5 of filename>.jsp? Beyond this (and other shortening techniques) I have nothing to give you. Sorry

Comment: The hard limit in most of the filesystems Linux supports is 255 or 256 characters (which incidentally, is also true of NTFS).  That's not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The filename you have given as an example is fine:

```
kevin@latte:~/miscdev/j$ touch 'everything.jsp_Q_browserId=firefox&themeId=controlpanel&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&t=1249034302000'
kevin@latte:~/miscdev/j$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kevin kevin 0 2009-07-30 17:07 everything.jsp_Q_browserId=firefox&themeId=controlpanel&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&t=1249034302000
```

I imagine the problem is that you are passing that filename to a shell un-escaped, and it is interpreting the & character.  Put the filename in single-quotes, as I have in my example.

Comment: but the error that it says is my filename is too long. by the way im using Ubuntu 9.04